# Javascript regex replace - Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to remove non-numeric characters from a string while typing, but it's not working in Chrome/Safari - anyone know a workaround?

The problem with Chrome is that if for example you enter 4 numbers, then a letter, it clears the text box and starts again, whereas other browsers just remove the letter.

Here is the code I have:

```
$('input[type=number]').bind('keyup', function (e) {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, '');
});
```

Many thanks

Comment: You could use `/\D+/` instead of `/[^0-9]+/`

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `this.value` use `$(this).val()`:

```
$('input[type=number]').bind('keyup', function (e) {
    $(this).val( $(this).val().replace(/[^0-9]+/g, '') );
});
```

Comment: @Christophe That's true but the problem was in the field's value setter/getter.

Comment: Can you clarify the difference between your jQuery code and OP's vanilla-js one? Which was this setter/getter problem?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, in Chrome text in an input of type number is considered invalid, and `this.value` returns an empty string.

To address this, what you can do is just use a regular input of type text.

```
$('input').bind('keyup', function (e) {
  this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, '');
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's for a mobile site and need to tag the field with number so the numeric pad opens on the phone instead of the regular keyboard

Comment: @e-on then I am afraid you are out of luck. I found more information: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18853513/485406 and Chrome behaves according to the specs.

Comment: btw if the numeric pad opens, you should not be bothered with non-numeric characters, right?