# How to get content length of invalid input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an element:

```
<input type="number">
```

When I type in $500, it fails validation, so

```
console.log("el.value");
//returns ""
```

This is expected.

Here's the question:
**How can I check that there is content?**

I'm trying to show/hide placeholder text (no, I can't use the native stuff). It needs to be `type="number"` because I need to force the mobile number keyboard.

Any thoughts?

**Update:**
From the responses below I can see that I wasn't clear enough in my question.

1) I need to use JavaScript to tell me whether there is content in the input. (I don't need to extract it, I just need to see whether there is content).

This is tricky, because invalid content (like putting words in a number input field) means the value="" even if there is content typed in.

This is the exact problem I need to solve.

`inputEl.validity.valid` might work but I can't find any docs on how well it is supported across browsers.

Comment: :focus[value='']::-webkit-input-placeholder {   color: transparent;  }

Comment: I need a JS solution. CSS only will not solve my problem.

Comment: This answered it: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18852244/how-to-get-the-raw-value-an-input-type-number-field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the one that actually answered it:

[How to get the raw value an <input type="number"> field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18852244/how-to-get-the-raw-value-an-input-type-number-field)

Basically you can check input.validity.valid or input.validity.badInput.

Not supported in IE but good support elsewhere.

More details on it here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ValidityState

Answer (score 0):

Check if you can do something with that :

html

```
<input id="my-input" type="number">
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#my-input').on('input', function(){
        console.log($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Comment: Already tried this. `$(this).val()` returns false because the content isn't valid.

Answer (score 0):

At mobile device specially Samsung append value in field do not throw key press event,
you can validate the field with onChange="check(this)"

Comment: Firing the event is not the problem. It's determining whether there is content in the input.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (variablename==""){
    //no content
}
```

or

```
if (variablename.length==0){
    //no content
}
```

Comment: if zero is an invalid value then `if (variablename)` will also work

Comment: I added more clarifying comments. This will NOT solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the only reason you need to force the input type to be a number is for the number-pad, why don't you instead make `type="text"` and `pattern="\d*"`? This way you can handle and check the input any way you'd like, but still, force the number-pad to show.

`<input type="text" pattern="\d*">`

Comment: I need the 'number' keyboard, not the 'tel' keyboard. Or else your method would make total sense.