# Any workaround of Opera 12's input type=number validity behavior?

Tags: javascript, html, validation, opera, constraint-validation-api

I was just troubleshooting an issue with a library of mine but it boils down to being something related with Opera behavior. Now, I haven't found big warnings anywhere on this issue, so my guess is that I'm missing something, or that there's a workaround that I just don't know of.

Specifically, take a simple code like this:

```
<input type="number" id="myNumber" />
```

On Opera 12.16, the input type=number is supported, so it'll correctly display a type=number input.

If the user enters a valid value, say "123", then:

```
var myInput = document.getElementById('myNumber');
myInput.value // => "123"
myInput.validity // => { valid: true, typeMismatch: false, ... }
myInput.validity.badInput // undefined
```

Now, if the user enters "123a", then:

```
var myInput = document.getElementById('myNumber');
myInput.value // => ""
myInput.validity // => { valid: true, typeMismatch: false, ... } -- why valid: true?
myInput.validity.badInput // undefined
```

Furthermore: `myInput.willValidate` returns `true` and `myInput.checkValidity()` returns `true` as well.

So, how can I actually check for bad input in input type=number on this version of Opera? (Consider an empty string is and should be valid input.)

Comment: Firefox seems to behave pretty much the same way, no?

Comment: @Pointy are you referring to a specific version of Firefox? I just tried with 32.0 and while it does the same, Firefox _does_ set `myInput.validity.badInput` to `true`, which is enough to detect up the problem, it also sets `valid` to `false`.

Comment: "why valid: true?" see http://stackoverflow.com/a/18853513/248058

Comment: @Knu I understand I should not be able to get the value if it's invalid, but I still don't understand why Opera would set `valid` to true if it's not. Is it giving me the validityStatus of the internal value (empty string) rather than the user input?

Comment: Yes, it's giving you the validityStatus of the value that would be used if the form was sent. The weird thing is that I can't seem to find a way to retrieve the input's value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
element.focus();
document.execCommand("SelectAll");
window.getSelection().focusNode.selectionStart;
```

This returns the length of the text entered in the input. Using it you can distinguish between an empty input and an invalid value. Remember to add an exception for tab.