# Regular Expression to replace alphabets/spaces with zero 0

Tags: regex, html, validation

```
<input type="number" min="1"  onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^\d]/,'')"name="Qty[]" placeholder="Qty" value="0">
```

This is my html input and using this regular expression I am able to replace all alphabets. Input gets blanked.
Although I tried putting in zero like so

```
onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^\d]/,'0')"
```

But it does not replace it with zero. Also the above provided expression replaces the whole string, whereas I want to if I input '1234a'
it just removes the 'a' . So either anyone could tell me how to replace the whole alphabets with 0 or just removes the alphabets from the input.

Sample inputs:
1234a

Intended outputs:
0 or 1234

Comment: add `g` modifier `onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^\d]/g,'')"` . Could you provide a sample input along with expected output?

Comment: ^i tried that. it still replaces the whole text. Also i updated my post for sample inputs and expected outputs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why it is so is because you won't be able to get the raw value of `input[type=number]` using `this.value` unless it's a number. In any other case, it would return an empty string. See [How to get the raw value an <input type="number"> field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18852244/how-to-get-the-raw-value-an-input-type-number-field)

Instead, what you can do is use an input type of text instead i.e.

```
<input type="text" min="1"  onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^\d]/g,'0')"name="Qty[]" placeholder="Qty" value="0">
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jcs2zh5e/

Also, you were missing the global modifier which would have caused the regex to not replace all the alphabets and just the first one, in cases when the user `pastes` some value into the field. To tackle that, added `g`.