# HTML input type number does not return value when having ., values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My project having requirement to show iphone keyboard with number, dot and comma values. I have tried to use `type="tel"`, but it does not show dot comma values.

Then decide to use type="number", its allows all values but when trying to retrieve values with dot,comma jQuery returns empty string.

HTML:

```
<input id="idNumberTest" type="number"/>
```

JS:

```
$(this).val()
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Boopathi_Sakthivel/hgLpc4ko/)

Comment: What kind of numerical notation works like 2323.,33? And are you sure the number tag supports it?

Comment: Thats html behaviour. https://www.aeyoun.com/posts/html5-input-number-localization.html

Comment: I have added text 2323.,33 for example. its for budget. Our project has requirement to allow user to enter comma and dot too.

Answer (score -1):

There's another thread with more information on valid values for input type number [How to get the raw value an <input type="number"> field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18852244/how-to-get-the-raw-value-an-input-type-number-field)

Comment: Samee, got more information from above thread. So, do i need to use input type text for my implementation rit ?

Comment: If you really need to have a comma(,) or any other character that the input type 'number' doesn't allow, then definitely you have to use input type 'text'.