# Get off-type content from html input

Tags: javascript, html, validation, input

I'm writing some validation for a form which includes an  tag with type="number". If non-numeric text is entered in the input box, getting the element with javascript and checking the value returns an empty string (in Chrome and Firefox at least).

[image: Non-numeric text in type="number" field]

```
var input = document.getElementById('inputId');
// ->   <input type="number" id="inputId">

console.log('The value is: ', input.value);
// ->   The value is:

console.log(typeof inputs.value);
// ->   string
```

Is there a way to get whatever is in the input if the entered text doesn't match the input's "type" attribute?

Comment: Why do you need the invalid value?

Comment: Would like to be able to throw a validation error message, but there's no way to distinguish between an empty box (valid) and invalid text entered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer here thanks to @Michael Perrenoud
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18853513/786096

TL;DR switch to type="text" if you need to customize the validation