# Why 1. returns an empty string when I try to get value of an input type number using javascript and html5?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a normal input as follows:

```
<input type="number" name="quantity" id="myInput">
```

If I type "1." (without the quotes of course) when I try to get the value of the input with

```
document.getElementById("myInput").value
```

Only an empty string is obtained.
Is there any other way to get the "1." input with javascript?

#### Edit

I am working using Polymer 1.0 and databinding, so in my example I showed using normal JavaScript syntax with the intention of finding a solution to my problem using only javascript.
I just want to know how to access a property that returns the value of the input, and which I believe should be stored in some property of the object.

Comment: Can you please show a more complete example of your code, especially the JavaScript?

Comment: And you do have an event handler, otherwise you're only getting the value on pageload?

Comment: I tested the code you provided in the console and it worked fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the raw value an <input type="number"> field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18852244/how-to-get-the-raw-value-an-input-type-number-field)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to get invalid values:

1. Focus the input.
2. Select its contents using [execCommand()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand).
3. Grab the selection using [window.getSelection()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection).

**Example:**

```js
document.querySelector('input[type="submit"]').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var inp= document.getElementById('myInput');
  
  inp.focus();
  document.execCommand('SelectAll');
  var value = window.getSelection().toString();

  document.getElementById('output').textContent = value;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" name="quantity" id="myInput">
<input type="submit">
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This works perfect! Even works without jquery.

Answer (score 3):

If you use `<input type="number">` the element is enriched with an extra attribute, `valueAsNumber`. So instead of

```
document.getElementById("myInput").value
```

use

```
document.getElementById("myInput").valueAsNumber
```

`valueAsNumber` will return `NaN` instead of blank if the value entered in the input not is convertable to a number. There is also a `validity` attribute holding information of the status of the current value, both according to the value as supposed number but also according to the number input's  *settings*, i.e "why is the number invalid".

**Fun with number inputs, try this out in various browsers :**

```html
<input type="number" name="quantity" id="myInput" ><br>
<input type="text" id="value" ><br>
<input type="text" id="valueAsNumber" ><br>
<input type="text" id="validity" ><br>
```

```js
document.getElementById("myInput").onkeyup = function() {
  document.getElementById("value").value = this.value;
  document.getElementById("valueAsNumber").value = this.valueAsNumber;
  document.getElementById("validity").value = '';
  for (validity in this.validity) {
     if (this.validity[validity]) {
       document.getElementById("validity").value+=validity+' ';
     }
  }
}
```

actually quite informative, if you want to investigate exactly **why** you get an empty value back from the input -> **http://jsfiddle.net/oaewv2Lr/** Have tried with Chrome, Opera and FF - Chrome seems to be the most "forgiving" browser of those three.

Answer (score 0):

Update:  It seems that your use of `type="number"` means that certain values won't come back.  You can switch it to a `type="text"` and do the checking yourself:

```js
document.getElementById('mySubmit').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var value = document.getElementById('myInput').value;
  if ( value != parseFloat(value) )
    alert('Invalid Number');
  document.getElementById('myOutput').innerHTML = value;
});
```

```html
<input type="text" name="quantity" id="myInput">
<input type="submit" id="mySubmit">
<div id="myOutput"></div>
```

Comment: not working when you enter `1.`, that is what OP has asked.

Answer (score 0):

It won't work if you will enter `1.`, as `1.` is not a valid number.

Comment: it works very well -> **http://jsfiddle.net/EJZ48/781/** (in chrome) perhaps this is a browser issue ....

Comment: @davidkonrad uhh, he's right. the spec states `The value attribute, if specified and not empty, must have a value that is a valid floating-point number.` See the [w3 specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#number-state-(type=number))

Comment: @davidkonrad try entering `1.` (dont miss the period `.`)!

Comment: @void, it works with `1.` (and even `2.` :) but not with `1..` of course (but this was not the question either) - I am curius what browser OP use. Working on chrome / Ubuntu.

Comment: @davidkonrad:  A slight modification to your code, and it stops working for me in Chrome as soon as I type the decimal point.  Does it still work for you?:  http://jsfiddle.net/eqp8q2ro/

Comment: @RickHitchcock, Yes! The same as before. `1.` works in chrome as I tried out with. But it does not work in FireFox, it returns blank. So it is as I expected, with all those `<input type="xxx">` there is **still** huge differences in how the various browsers supports it.

Comment: Really interesting.  Seems like there should be some way to access the input value, even if it's invalid.