# Typed decimal disappears from HTML text input of type 'number' in browser

Tags: html, css

*Found the answer here:* https://stackoverflow.com/a/18853513/983173 *Also, see update below.*

---

Weird behavior I've been wrestling with all day.  I would very much like to be able to provide mobile users of my website with the numeric keypad when they use my site, as a shortcut for them.  I've been approaching this by setting my HTML input type to 'number' as seen here:

```
<input id='blah' class='blah' type='number' placeholder='blah'>
```

This worked, but I still want the site to look decent for PC users so I had to find help removing the spinner buttons that PC browsers add when you change an HTML input type to 'number' so I added this in CSS:

```
input[type='number'] {
    -moz-appearance:textfield;
}

input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

This also worked, so now I had HTML text inputs of type number, so that mobile users would automatically get the numeric keypad and PC users would not see ugly spinners.  **However** at this point, I cannot type decimal '.' characters into my text fields in PC browsers.  It works on mobile but not on PC.  When I strike the '.' key, I actually visibly see the decimal appear in the text area, then disappear, but using an event listener on the input element, listening for a 'keyup' event, the value of the text input never reflects the '.' character being entered at all.

What have I missed?

**Update:** after copying these HTML and CSS elements into isolation (zer00ne thank you), I've traced the problem to my JavaScript, and past there to the implementation of the number input type's `.value` member in particular.  My JavaScript is pulling the value of the number input, doing some string work with it, then putting it back.  For some reason, I can't detect the trailing decimal character '.' in the screen-visible text of the input field, so when I pull the value of the number input it drops the decimal every time I type on before putting it back.  Is there any other way to detect a trailing decimal in a number input or get the raw value out so that i can see it?

Comment: define `step=0.01 / 0.001` based on number of decimal places to support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18853513/983173

In short, the number type input is specified to return a numeric value, not a string, when `numberInput.value` is used.

In other words, if a user types `42.` into a number input, and JS calls `numberInput.value` on that input, the browser will **by design** return 42 as a number, not "42." as a string.  *Because if you're working with a number*, the specification assumes, *you would never want to know if there were a decimal on the end*.  There is no way you can access the 'raw' string value of a number input (in other words, no way to detect a trailing decimal), and no workaround unless you want to do key capturing or other inconvenient work to handle and track the existence of decimals, which is what I ultimately had to do.

I'm going to try to update the question to make this more clear.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

I see what your'e saying now, when I type the decimal, the output disappears. Fortunately, it reappears when you enter any number on the right of the decimal. So it probably interprets that period (".") as part of a string until it is surrounded by valid numbers.

---

I made a test of your code and used the input event to see if the decimal value carried over and looks like it does. Am I missing something?

Tested on Windows 8 Firefox and Chrome

```js
var num = document.getElementById('num');
num.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  var out1 = document.getElementById('out1');
  out1.value = num.value;
}, false);
```

```css
input[type='number'] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<input id='num' class='num' type='number' placeholder='Number' />

<output id="out1"></output>
```

Comment: Your solution seems to work, I must be doing something wrong somewhere else, in JS maybe.  I didn't think that would be causing the problem but now I suppose it must be.

Comment: See update for possible reason, I don't think it was your code. I believe you were **too** over observant (which is a good thing). I honestly would've never noticed that inconsistancy.

Comment: I am at a loss, but I'm getting different behavior.  No decimals are accepted under any condition, including the situation you described in your update.  Any time I press a decimal, it is deleted and never reappears.  I can guess this is going to be an anticlimactic solution if I find it, something silly in my JS that was interfering.

Comment: Most likely, but you do see what I see in this demo correct? Try isolating your code block by block, and when running it, check your console and source tabs.

Comment: Yes, your demo worked perfectly. I also found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18852244/how-to-get-the-raw-value-an-input-type-number-field explaining that the implementation of `numberInput.value` is specified to output a numeric value, which will not include a trailing zero if it is an integer because why would it? You can never access the 'raw' value of a number input, that is by design and there is no workaround. The only option is to fall back to the plain text input type, as I see others doing in the event (like mine) that JS needs access to an input's 'raw' value.

Comment: I updated the question to be much more specific to the details revealed in your comment and the experimentation you led me to.  The questions sort of becomes, *is there a workaround for this?* and it seems there is not.

Comment: Very enlightening, thanks @fts_acer , I upped your question earlier for your efforts, much appreciated, sir. :)