# Restrict Exponents and periods(.) in numeric textbox html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a numeric textbox, by default numeric textbox allows Exponents and periods.
How do i restrict that?

One of the method i can think of is using string.replace on input event however it is not working as expected. Below is my code..

HTML

```
     <input type='number' class='number'>
```

JavaScript

```
     $(".number").on('input', function () {
            this.value = this.value.replace(/e|E|\./g, ''); // Remove e, E, and period(.)
            if (this.value.length > 4) {
                this.value = this.value.slice(0, 4);
            }
        });
```

When i enter string '2e' in textbox, entire input is getting removed if above code is ran. i just wants to remove e, E or period from input string not entire input.

Is there a way to achieve this.

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8vanqrev/1/)

Answer BY *nichel* is working like a charm, now my problem is how do i restrict the same in PASTE event.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically you want to allow just numbers? Then restrict the keys by keycode & remove excess chars on paste

```
$(".number").keypress(function(e){
   return e.keyCode>47&&e.keyCode<58;
}).paste(function(){
   $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/\D/g,''));
})
```

And since you'd like the max length to be 4, just add `max="9999"`:

```
<input type='number' class='number' max="9999">
```

Comment: _since you'd like the max length to be 5_ OP wants **4**

Comment: @Tushar Oh, I noticed `.slice(0, 4)` and thought wrongly. Indeed.

Answer (score 0):

`input[type=number]` returns `""`(blank string) if input value is not valid.

You can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18852244/how-to-get-the-raw-value-an-input-type-number-field) post for more information.

I would suggest you to use `input[type=tel]` instead. It also has a `maxLength` attribute so you so not have to worry about trimming extra values.

You can even replace your regex to `/[^0-9]/`. This will replace all characters except numbers.

[Sample Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8vanqrev/3/).

So you final code would look like: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8vanqrev/4/)