# Get invalid value from input type number

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am using input type number. How can I get the value from this when its not valid. For example using type number and printing just 'e' thats not valid by itself.

I am using React but I think this question is very general.

```
onChange(event) {
  console.log(event.target.value) //is empty string when not using number
}

<form novalidate>
  <input type="number" onChange={this.onChange}>
</form>
```

Comment: You can't, `e` is allowed because it refers to exponents. you `<input type="text">` instead and listen to changes using the `input` event. You can allways convert for number using `parseFloat` or just the unary `+`.

Comment: @Noctisdark, thanks. I understand the reason i can write e in that field. The reason I need to capture is for validation message. I am creating a chat soo I need to write back exactly what the user typed.

Comment: @pethel did you find a solution

Comment: You may have already checked this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18852244/how-to-get-the-raw-value-an-input-type-number-field and I was trying use <input type="number" id="myInput" onChange="onChange(this.id)"> but this is also failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually possible (at least in Chromium-based browers like Chrome and Edge), it's just a pain. You can get it via the selection interface:

```
const input = /*...the input...*/;
input.select();
const text = getSelection().toString();
```

No luck on Firefox, sadly.

Live Example:

```js
const theInput = document.getElementById("the-input");
const theButton = document.getElementById("the-btn");

function saveSelection() {
    const selection = getSelection();
    const range = selection.rangeCount === 0 ? null : selection.getRangeAt(0);
    return range;
}

function restoreSelection(range) {
    const selection = getSelection();
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
}

function getRawText(input) {
    const sel = saveSelection();
    input.select();
    const text = getSelection().toString();
    restoreSelection(sel);
    return text;
}

theButton.addEventListener("click", event => {
    const value = theInput.value;
    const text  = getRawText(theInput);
    console.log(`value = "${value}", but text = "${text}"`);
});
```

```html
<p>
Copy some invalid numeric text (like <code>9-9</code>) and paste it into this field:
</p>
<input type="number" id="the-input">
<p>
Then click here: <input type="button" id="the-btn" value="Go">
</p>
```

Answer (score 3):

According to my findings there is no solution to this specific problem.
The only way to get it is to set the `input` as `type="text"` and decide within the function about the validity:
(source: [Validate decimal numbers in JavaScript - IsNumeric()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-decimal-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric))

```js
function onChange(event) {
  if(!isNaN(parseFloat(event.value)) && isFinite(event.value)){
    console.log("It's numeric: " + event.value);
  }
  else {
    console.log("It's not numeric: " + event.value);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onChange="onChange(this)">
```

You have to call the onChange JS Function in this way `onChange="onChange(this)"` and use event.value instead of `event.target.value` in order to get the correct result.

```js
function onChange(event) {
  console.log(event.value)
}
```

```html
<form novalidate>
  <input type="number" onChange="onChange(this)">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, but no. Try to just type 'e' in your solution and blur. You will get a blank line.

Comment: @user874774 is it necessary to write it in reactjs?

Comment: I should use it in react but I think this is very general problem. But i will not use jQuery or any other framework if thats the question.

Comment: @user874774 this is my only solution about this problem

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get you, but I think you're looking to get the input value. You're looking to target the `value`, but your tag doesn't have this attribute. In this case you need to add `value ={this.state.value}` to the input tag as a prop and add the new state in the constructor. `this.state = {value: ''}`

Comment: se my comment in the answer from @Luca Jung