# Allow only number digits in input type regex. issue is i am able to type this(1.) , want to prevent it

Tags: javascript, html, regex, validation, input

MY CODE

```js
function validate(e, id) {
  var reg = new RegExp('^\\d+$');
  if (reg.test($("#" + id).val())) {
    var value = $("#" + id).val();
    alert(value);
  } else {
    alert("fail");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="input-type" type="number" id="number-input" oninput="validate(event,'number-input');">
```

This accept 1.(dot after any digits) value rest all is good.

Comment: you want to pass only integers?

Comment: Yes but it take dot after any digit.

Comment: You want to match a number like `1.23`?

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/yoam70tL/

Comment: For 1.23 it works fine but when you enter 123. it fails

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew event.charCode fails in many devices like Samsung.In Samsung many keys has 443 charCode. Don't want to use this option.

Comment: @GopalSingh Can you use `event.key` on `keypress` or `keyup` to detect the dot and prevent the event (or remove the dot)? May make up such solution for you.

Comment: @ilyaigpetrov check my updated snippet and fiddle

Comment: @ilyaigpetrov not able to detect dot when use type="number"

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `<input type="tel" ...>`. This way when user types `1.` you will receive `1.` only and not `1` and it will also open number keypad on mobile.

```js
function validate(e, id) {
  var reg = /^[0-9]*(\.(?=[0-9]+))*[0-9]+$/;
  var value = $("#" + id).val();
  if (reg.test(value)) {
    console.log(value);
  } else {
    console.log("fail");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="input-type" type="tel" id="number-input" oninput="validate(event,'number-input');">
```

You can also refer to [How to get the raw value an <input type="number"> field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18852244/how-to-get-the-raw-value-an-input-type-number-field) for more information in *why `1.` returns `1` and not `1.`*

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code that might help you.In the below code when the user types `.` it is replaced by `null`.It only accepts digits.This is for `input type="text"`.The variable `currValue` has the value of the input.

> The search() method searches a string for a specified value, and returns the position of the match.The search value can be string or a regular expression.This method returns -1 if no match is found.

Then I am using `.replace()`

> The replace() method searches a string for a specified value, or a regular expression, and returns a new string where the specified values are replaced.

Here I am replacing it with null if the regex doesn't match.The regex `[^0-9]` checks if not digit.

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/j2uhtx9u/1/)

Here is the code:

```js
$(function() {
  $('input').bind('keyup', function(event) {
    var currValue = $(this).val();

    if (currValue.search(/[^0-9]/) != -1) {

      alert('Only numerical inputs please');
    }

    $(this).val(currValue.replace(/[^0-9]/, ''));
    alert($(this).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>Digits Only:
  <input type="text" />
</label>
<br>
<br>
```

**EDIT :**
In `input type="number"` we have to force it to always accept the updated `val` since many events does not work in it.So for that reason I have to update the existing value with the updated value after each event.

So I added

```
var v = $(this).val();
$(this).focus().val("").val(v);
```

So that each time the input is focused the value get updated with the existing value.

[**UPDATED FIDDLE FOR INPUT TYPE NUMBER**](https://jsfiddle.net/j2uhtx9u/4/)

Updated snippet:

```js
$(function() {
  $('input').bind('keyup input', function(event) {
    var v = $(this).val();
    $(this).focus().val("").val(v);

    var currValue = $(this).val();

    if (currValue.search(/[^0-9]/) != -1) {

      alert('Only numerical inputs please');
    }

    $(this).val(currValue.replace(/[^0-9]/, ''));
    alert($(this).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Digits Only:
  <input type="number" />
</label>
<br>
<br>
```

**EDIT 2 :** For special case `+` and `-`.I think its a bug I am not sure but check the below snippet.It works for all the cases.Hope it helps.

[**FINAL FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/j2uhtx9u/6/)

```js
$(function() {
  $('input').bind('keyup', function(event) {
    var v = $(this).val();
    $(this).focus().val("").val(v);
    var currValue = $(this).val();
    $(this).val(currValue.replace(/[^0-9]/, ''));
    alert(v);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Digits Only:
  <input type="number" name="test" min=0 save="" oninput="validity.valid ? this.save = value : value = this.save;">
</label>
<br>
<br>
```

Hope it helps.For any other doubt feel free to ask.

Comment: In a comment to my answer author says he wants numeric keyboard on mobile.

Comment: Yes @ilyaigpetrov right . I already know it works with type=" text" but I want number keyboard.

Comment: @shubhamagrawal nice trick, I think it's the answer. Remove old code, please.

Comment: @ilyaigpetrov don't know why I am not able to edit right now its giving some error.I will as soon as possible

Comment: @shubhamagrawal can you please explain the code. when I press + and - key the text got clear.

Comment: @GopalSingh check the explanation of the code.Hope this helps.For any other doubt feel free to ask.

Comment: No check the updated fiddle its working.Which browser are you using

Comment: I am using chrome but I will use this code for mobile application.

Comment: Its working I checked the code even on moblie. I am not sure why are you facing this error.Yesterday only I made sure that it supports all the device

Comment: @shubhamagrawal it's not working in both (when type + or - ) cases.

Comment: @GopalSingh check the final snippet.This will work under all the possible cases.Hope this solves the issue.

Comment: By this, there are many issues like when user enter dot or comma etc before entered text(.2131324 ) its shows focus issue.

Comment: @GopalSingh what focus issue are you talking about.Do you want it to loose focus if the input is wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138640/discussion-between-gopal-singh-and-shubham-agrawal).

Comment: @GopalSingh did you find a solution to your problem

Answer (score 0):

It work as fallow:

```
1   pass
1.  fail
1.1 pass
```

```js
function validate(e, id) {
  var value = $("#" + id).val() + "";
  if (new RegExp('^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$').test(value)
 || ((new RegExp('^[0-9]+').test(value) && !value.includes(".")))
) {
    var value = $("#" + id).val();
    alert($("#" + id).val() + "->" + value);
  } else {
    alert("fail " + $("#" + id).val());
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="input-type" type="text" id="text-input" oninput="validate(event,'text-input');">
```

Comment: Not working because I am using type="number" and can't change it to "text"

Comment: Is there any solution using type="number"

Comment: @GopalSingh nop, because when using type number, 1. will be converted to 1, you will never get the dot

Comment: Thanks but still my requirement is same