# Capture dot for Input type number in Android Device and Browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In below snippet code, If i give inputs "9999999999" and "9999999999." in console log both displays the same result "999999999" with out dot.

Am trying to capture dot symbol even after number. Here, only input type number is allowed cannot use text or any other type.

Text box is for number

```
Number: <input type='number' id=txtNumber'/>
```

And it's javascript function

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
   $('#txtNumber').keyup(function () {
     var numbers = $(this).val(); console.log("numbers", numbers);
   });
});
```

code at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JLJMW/1692/)

Please help to find solution.

Comment: Because the value of `"9999999999."` casted to a number is `9999999999`. Since it's `type='number'` then `.val()` will convert the value into a number.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the raw value an <input type="number"> field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18852244/how-to-get-the-raw-value-an-input-type-number-field)

Comment: Possibly [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - *why* do you want to do this, what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is you set `type='number'`.
I suggest you set `type='text'` and use regular expressions to check if the value in the input is a number(include dot) or not:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {  
       $('#txtNumber').keyup(function () {
        if ($(this).val().match(/^[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*$/)){ //check if your value is number or not
         var numbers = $(this).val(); console.log("numbers", numbers);
         }
       });
    });
```

Comment: Thai, input type should be number.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function to do this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#txtNumber').keyup(function () {
            var numbers = $(this).val(); console.log("numbers", numbers);
            // dump(numbers);
            numbers = parseInt(numbers).toFixed(2);
            console.log(numbers);
        });
    });
```

It will give you your desired output.

Comment: You problem should test your code. Not only will this not work but you will get an error: `numbers.toFixed is not a function`.

Comment: Himanshu - It generated error like numbers.toFixed not a function.

Comment: Himanshu, your edited snippet converting existing data, I need to capture but not want to change.

Comment: Capture means can you write down the desired outcome?