# What's the function of comma when present in <input type="number"> field?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, validation, input

This is an HTML5 question but related to Angular.

I've been trying to prevent the input of more than one dot in a field with `<input type="number">` inside an Angular form. I've tried:

- Directive in input element with keypress event to prevent multiple dots.
- Custom validator to raise an error when more than one dot it's present.

For now, I'm trying to prevent multiple dot/comma input with a directive applied to the input, removing dot/comma when there is already present a dot/comma or when the input value is an invalid number.

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[single-dot]'
})
export class SingleDotDirective {
  private el: HTMLInputElement;

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {
    this.el = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
  }

  @HostListener('keypress', ['$event'])
  onkeypress(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
    const invalidInput = this.el.validity.badInput;
    const inputCharSeparator =
      String.fromCharCode(event.charCode) === '.' ||
      String.fromCharCode(event.charCode) === ',';
    const alreadyWithSeparator =
      this.el.value.toString().indexOf('.') !== -1 ||
      this.el.value.toString().indexOf(',') !== -1;

    if (inputCharSeparator && (alreadyWithSeparator || invalidInput)) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
}
```

But I found a problem, when I try to capture the current input value, the browser returns an empty string when the number is invalid. You can see the reason here: [How to get the raw value an <input type="number"> field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18852244/how-to-get-the-raw-value-an-input-type-number-field)

So for example, for a field like:

```
<input type="number" id="edQuantity">
```

`edQuantity.value` will return:

- `"2.1"` if input number is `2.1`
- `""` if input number is `2.`
- `"2.1"` if input number is `2,1`
- **`2` if input number is `2,`**

If I check `edQuantity.validity.badInput` for the last case I'm getting `false`.

My code can't detect that the value of the input is bad when a comma is present, so you can input values like:

`2,.22`

So, my questions are:

1. Why the validation result it's different for `,`?
2. What's the function of comma when present in  field?
3. Any idea to fix my code?

I've tested this in Chrome and Fx.

Thanks!

Comment: Avoid input type number, just use text.

Comment: That's a bad approach if you want the number keyboard to show on mobile.

Comment: do you need an example of validator for multiple ',' or '.'? What exacly do you mean by "prevent multiple dot (or comma) input"? Make the angular form invalid?

Comment: `type="number"` adds some nice things like @pascalpuetz said, number keyboard on mobiles but also 'add' / 'minus' buttons.

Comment: Comma is used as decimal operator in some places in Europe, that's why it's still a valid input with comma (,)

Comment: @TomaszKula I don't want the user to input things like `2........2` or `2,,,,2` these values don't raise exceptions, and when you submit the form, that property is sent with a empty string value "". My goal is to try to minimize these situations allowing only one comma or dot.

Comment: @HaseebJehanzeb yeah, I'm trying to prevent multiple `.` or `,` but comma validation is different from dot validation in HTML5, Why?

Comment: are you using `@angular/forms`?

Comment: @TomaszKula yes, angular forms with validation, I also tried to create a custom validator to detect bad values, but HTML5 `.value` returns an empty string when the value is invalid.