# How can I tell if an <input type=number> is blank vs. has an invalid value?

Tags: javascript

If a user types an invalid value (ex: "1.2.3") into an `<input type=number>`, then Chrome and Firefox report the `<input>`'s `value` property as `""` rather than `"1.2.3"`.

So, how do I tell if the user typed in an invalid number into the `<input>` or just left it blank?

I tried using the `valueAsNumber` property but it's `NaN` in both cases.

```js
function showInputValue() {
  const inputValue = document.getElementById("numberInput").value;
  const inputValueAsNumber = document.getElementById("numberInput").valueAsNumber;
  
  console.log(`value is: "${inputValue}"\nvalueAsNumber is: "${inputValueAsNumber}"`);
}

document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", showInputValue)
```

```html
<input type="number" id="numberInput" placeholder="try entering text"/>
<button id="btn">Show value</button>
```

Answer (score 8):

Your input element has the `validity` property implementing the [`ValidityState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ValidityState) interface:

```
ValidityState {
  badInput: true,
  customError: false,
  patternMismatch: false,
  rangeOverflow: false,
  rangeUnderflow: false,
  stepMismatch: false,
  tooLong: false,
  tooShort: false,
  typeMismatch: false,
  valid: false,
  valueMissing: false
}
```

From here you can study all validity states (`valueMissing`, `badInput`, etc...)

You can get a reference to your input using `document.querySelector`.

In your case the empty input will set the `valueMissing` flag, and the "1.2.3" input will set the `badInput` flag.

Comment: Would that say what the original value was?

Comment: Not sure (I will check it later more in depth...), you would save it on change event to element dataset for example

Comment: Thanks!  Actually, `valueMissing` is `false` even when the value *is* missing... maybe because the field isn't mandatory.  The `badInput` flag works for Chrome and Firefox, but it's not on IE11.  So I guess a check like `input.validity.badInput || isNan(input.value)` tells us that there is text, but it's invalid.

Comment: There is a very similar question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18852244/how-to-get-the-raw-value-an-input-type-number-field?noredirect=1&lq=1) with no working solution or hack, but with reasonable explanations

Answer (score 2):

According to the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18852244/how-to-get-the-raw-value-an-input-type-number-field), you won't be able to get the value of an input field of type `number` unless it's a valid numeric input.

On the other hand, you can make the input field of type `text` instead and validate it with the help of regex like this:

```js
window.onload = ()=>{
  let numBox = document.getElementById('number-box');
  let button = document.getElementById('show-value');
  let pattern = /^\d*(\.\d+)?$/;
  numBox.addEventListener('input', function(){
    if(pattern.test(this.value) && this.value !== ''){
      console.log('valid');
    }
    else {
      console.log('invalid!');
    }
  });
  button.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    alert(`The current value in the input field is ${numBox.value}`);
  });
};
```

```html
<input type="text" id="number-box">
<input type="button" id="show-value" value="Show Value">
```

Also, here's a [working example](https://codepen.io/RaysOfTheSun/pen/yRKvwm?editors=1111) :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery **$.isNumeric()** function for numeric validation like the following.

```
function showInputValue() {
    const inputValue = document.getElementById("numberInput").value;
    //const inputValueAsNumber = 
    //document.getElementById("numberInput").valueAsNumber;

    if(inputValue !== '' && $.isNumeric(inputValue))
       {
         alert("number is ok");
        }
    else if(inputValue  == '')
        {
         alert("input is empty");
        }
   else {
        alert("Number is invalid");
        }
   }
```

Comment: I don't see how that could work, as I said above, `inputValue` will be `""` regardless of whether the `<input>` is actually blank or has a value like "1.2.3".

Comment: check the updated answer. now it also check if the input is empty.

Comment: As I said above, this won't work because `inputValue` will be `""` regardless of whether the `<input>` is actually blank or has a value like `"1.2.3"`