# Reset form invalid values

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Here's a sample form:

```js
var form = document.querySelector('form');

function detectChange() {
  var inputs = form.querySelectorAll('input');
  for (var input of inputs) {
    if (input.value != input.defaultValue) {
      return true;
    }
  }
}

form.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (detectChange() && confirm('Are you sure you want to reset?')) {
    form.reset();
  }
});
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="number">
  <input type="number" value="7">
  <button type="button">Reset</button>
</form>
```

I'd like the reset button to work even if the user enters non-numeric values.

Comment: how can a user input non-numeric value to input of type number?

Comment: @SyedMehtabHassan: You can do it even in Chrome: copy and paste some text into the input fields.

Comment: loop over the elements of form and set the value = " "

Comment: @SyedMehtabHassan type in "e1231e222" that is invalid but it lets you enter it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/18853513/3744304

Comment: NOTE: A "normal" reset for `<input type="number" value="45" />` for example would reset to 45.  Do you wish that to behave the same as a "reset" type? IF so, some of these answers will fail.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss: "_Do you wish that to behave the same as a "reset" type?_" Yes.

Comment: I took the liberty of adding an example for folks :)

Comment: What if an empty value is a value that was created by the user? Such as an input having a default value of `10` `<input type="number" value="10" />` and being deleted by the user.

Comment: @connexo: Then the confirm occurs and when you OK, the input restores its default value, i.e. 10. Try it on my demo.

Comment: Is this solved with Mori's answer? or is the validation is not happening generically for both string and number yet?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you look at the `input` DOM object, there is a property `badInput` under `validity` object whose value is a `boolean`. For numeric entry or empty field, it's `false`. However it's `true` for non numeric values, which can *interestingly* be used in your case.

Note: Tested only on `firefox` and `safari`

```
input
|  +-- ...
|  +-- validity
|  |   +-- badInput
|  |   +-- ...
|  +-- ...
```

Using this knowledge you can modify the function to check for `badInput` to achieve what you want with minimal tweaking.

```
// non-empty and non default
if ((input.value && input.value != input.defaultValue) || input.validity.badInput)
```

```js
var form = document.querySelector('form');

function detectChange() {
  var inputs = form.querySelectorAll('input');
  for (var input of inputs) {
    if ((input.value && input.value != input.defaultValue) || input.validity.badInput) {
      return true;
    }
  }
}

form.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (detectChange() && confirm('Are you sure you want to reset?')) {
    form.reset();
  }
});
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="number">
  <input type="number" value="11">
  <button type="button">Reset</button>
</form>
```

Update:

update to cover:

> inputs with non-empty default values

Comment: seems to work fine on firefox, could you elaborate?

Comment: I was wrong, `input.value` will return `"0"` (a string) and not `0` which would evaluate to `false`.

Comment: yes, which i would say is a *little strange* given the input `type="number"`

Comment: Any `input` regardless of type will always only hold `string` values.

Comment: "_The HTMLFormElement.reset() method restores a form element's default values._" The default value isn't always an empty string. Your answer is already perfect. All you need to generalize your snippet to cover inputs with non-empty default values is the following: `if (input.value != input.defaultValue || input.validity.badInput)`: [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Mori/Lpzdrsk1/6/)

Comment: Updated my question to prevent the contusion.

Answer (score 2):

One alternative to approach your goal is using a set of standard `pseudo-classes`, like [:invalid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:invalid) and [:valid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:valid). Also note, we are going to use some array methods and features, like [Array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and the [Spread Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```js
var form = document.querySelector('form');

function detectChange()
{
    var invalids = form.querySelectorAll('input:invalid');
    var valids = form.querySelectorAll('input:valid');
    return (invalids.length > 0) || [...valids].some(i => i.defaultValue !== i.value);
}

form.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function()
{
    if (detectChange() && confirm('Are you sure you want to reset?'))
        form.reset();
});
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="number">
  <input type="number">
  <input type="number" value="7">
  <button type="button">Reset</button>
</form>
```

If you are able to use `placeholders` on your `inputs`, then another possible solution is to use the **CSS pseudo-class** [:placeholder-shown](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:placeholder-shown). However, give a check to the [browser's support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:placeholder-shown#Browser_compatibility) to be sure it will fit your need. Note it is **experimental** and is **not recommended** to use on production. Then, you can use the next `selector`:

```
input:not(:placeholder-shown)
```

to get all inputs where the `placeholder` is not shown, i.e, all **not-empty** inputs, and re-implement your code something like this:

```js
var form = document.querySelector('form');

function detectChange()
{
    var inputs = form.querySelectorAll(
        'input:not([value]):not(:placeholder-shown), input[value]'
    );
    return [...inputs].some(i => !i.defaultValue || i.defaultValue !== i.value);
}

form.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function()
{
    if (detectChange() && confirm('Are you sure you want to reset?'))
        form.reset();
});
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="number" placeholder="Insert a number">
  <input type="number" placeholder="Insert a number">
  <input type="number" value="7" placeholder="Insert a number">
  <button type="button">Reset</button>
</form>
```

Comment: "_we are going to use some array methods and features, like Array.some() and the Spread Syntax_" Do we really need to? Why not simply: `if (input.value != input.defaultValue || form.querySelectorAll('input:invalid').length)`: [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/t9ndo4ab/)

Comment: @Mike No, you don't need it, you have demonstrate it yourself. However I feel comfortable using they.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
<button type="button">Reset</button>
```

TO

```
<input type="reset" value="Reset"/>
```

Comment: "You should usually avoid including reset buttons in your forms. They're rarely useful, and are instead more likely to frustrate users who click them by mistake (often while trying to click the submit button)." [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/reset)

Comment: @Mori but the notice does not refer to the input `type=reset` specifically. It refers to the reset buttons in general. No matter how are you going to do that it's still a reset button which is *"rarely useful, and is instead more likely to frustrate users who click it by mistake"*

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek: The confirm dialog box prevents an unwanted reset of the form.

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the input fields and manually set values = "";

```js
var form = document.querySelector('form');

function detectChange() {
  var inputs = form.querySelectorAll('input');
  for (var input of inputs) {
    input.value = "";
  }
}

form.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (confirm('Are you sure you want to reset?')) {
    detectChange(); 
  }
});
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="number">
  <input type="number">
  <button type="button">Reset</button>
</form>
```

Comment: The button should work only when there’s a value. (a non-empty input field)

Comment: @Mori this was actually not mentioned in you question

Comment: @Mori if a non-numeric char is paste in a input tag it doesn't take it as a value you can check by using document.getElementsBytagName('input');

Comment: This fails to set the value to the reset (87) value in `<input type="number" value="87">`

Answer (score 0):

Just set an event listener for `onkeydown`, `onpaste` of the input element:

```
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=number]')
inputs.forEach((el) => el.onkeydown = el.onpaste = (event) => event.target.dataset.receivedEntry = 1)
```

Then check for the `input.dataset.receivedEntry` in **detectChange**:

```
function detectChange () {
  const inputs = form.querySelectorAll('input');
  for (var input of inputs) {
    if (input.dataset.receivedEntry) {
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss just add the event listener to `onpaste` event of the input. (UPDATED THE ANSWER)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a `button type="reset"`, and attach an event listener on the `form` that listens for `reset` events.

The main problem with your code is that your `detectChange()` function will never work for invalid input because browsers will always return the empty string for any non-numeric input if you ask for the value. This is by the specification. Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/18853513/3744304

The solution to fix this has been suggested originally in @naga - elixir - jar's answer. Edited my answer a) to make it working answer and b) to put it all together in a concise, ES6 way.

```js
const form = document.querySelector('form');

form.addEventListener('reset', (event) => {
  if (detectChange() && !confirm('Are you sure you want to reset?')) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});

function detectChange() { 
  return [...form.querySelectorAll('input')].some(el => el.validity.badInput || el.value !== el.defaultValue); 
};
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="number" value="87">
  <input type="number">
  <button type="reset">Reset</button>
</form>
```

Comment: This does not work if I enter an invalid number such as "e23e333"

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Added an explanation (and workaround) for that.

Comment: A side note: if you write something on one input and later you use `backspace` to delete all the characters, the confirm dialog will still triggers. However, I'm not sure if the OP wants this case to trigger the confirm dialog or not (since, after all,  there was some changes on the inputs).

Comment: @Shidersz: "_I'm not sure if the OP wants this case to trigger the confirm dialog or not_" The confirm dialog box should appear only when there’s a value — preferably a real value: number.

Comment: @Mori So it's desired that the confirm dialog does **not** appear in case the form only has either empty or invalid values?

Comment: Yes, that's OK.

Comment: Not really: as the question title suggests I'd like the reset button to clear invalid values as well. I don't really care if the confirm doesn't occur for invalid values.

Answer (score -1):

```js
var form = document.querySelector('form');
var btn = form.querySelector('button');
var inputs = form.querySelectorAll('input');
btn.disabled = true;
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (confirm('Are you sure you want to reset?')) {
    form.reset();
    btn.disabled = true;
  }
});

for (var input of inputs) {
  input.addEventListener('keypress', detectSpace)
  input.addEventListener('input', handleChange);
}

function handleChange(e) {
  var disabled = true;
  for (var input of inputs) {
    input.value = input.value.trim()
    if (input.value) {
      disabled = false
    }
  }
  btn.disabled = disabled
}

function detectSpace(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 32) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="number">
  <input type="number">
  <button type="button">Reset</button>
</form>
```

will this work? it prevents user from pasting into number by trimming the value inside `input type="number"`.

`detectSpace` is there because in firefox hitting space will delete the number because is not a valid one.

Comment: This prevents entry of a valid number with exponent "1e4" for example

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss it works in chrome and firefox, even with '1e4'. firefox converts it to 10000.

Comment: I used chrome an attempted to type 3e2 and it would not let me enter the "e" for the exponent.  It clears the field when I hit the "e"

Answer (score -1):

```
<form>
  <input type="number">
  <input type="number">
  <button type="button" onclick="resetData()">Reset</button>
</form>


function resetData(){
    var y = document.querySelectorAll('input,textarea');
        for (var i= 0; i < y.length; i++) {
        var id =y[i].id;
        if(y[i].value !=''&&y[i].value!= 'undefined'){
        document.getElementById(id).value="";
        }
        } 
}
```