# How to check input number is negative null?

Tags: javascript, numbers

For the numeric input element, is there a way to check if there is only a minus input? I can do this in a bad way in the example below. I'm looking for a more precise, simple method that I can access via the element.

When input is only `-` => `numberInput.value` equals to **empty string** also **innerText** and **innerHTML** equals to **empty string**.

```js
var lastKey;
var checkNegativeSign = function() {
  let numberInput = document.querySelector("input");
  if(lastKey === '-') {
    document.getElementById("result").innerText = "is negative";
  } else {
     document.getElementById("result").innerText = "";
  }
}

var onKeyUp = function(event) {
  // Should check Escape, ctrl etc.
  lastKey =event.key;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <input type="number" onkeyup="onKeyUp(event)" />
  <button onclick="checkNegativeSign()">Check Negative Sign</button>
  <div id="result"> </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I think it's simply because "-" is not a valid number so you get an empty value...
You should maybe make the type of your input "text", in that case you could get rid of the "onkeyup" event.

Comment: @Arcord `-` This is not a valid number, I agree with you, but to enter a negative value we start with it. So I expect the number element to give this information.

Comment: I understand the issue but unfortunately I don't think it's possible : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18852244/how-to-get-the-raw-value-an-input-type-number-field

Answer (score -2):

You could do

```js
    let sign = Math.sign(Number(document.querySelector("input").value))
    console.log(sign === 1? "positive": "negative")
```

Comment: when input only `-` and if i using `Math.sign(Number(document.querySelector("input").value))` return 0.

Comment: I don't get what you mean...
Could you clarify why are you putting `.value` on the end of Math.sign?

Comment: actually that `value`, I misspelled it at the end of the element.I edited my comment. 

Because `Math.sign(Number(document.querySelector("input")))` return `NaN`.