# String value for decimal field doesn't throw ValidationError in view but works fine in shell

Tags: html, django, django-forms

I created test project to figure this out.

Here is the form:

```
class PaymentForm(forms.Form):
  amount = forms.DecimalField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=2, required=False)
```

Everything works as expected in shell:

```
>>> from testapp.forms import PaymentForm
>>> f = PaymentForm({'amount': 'a'})
>>> f.errors
{'amount': ['Enter a number.']}
>>> f.is_valid()
False
```

But if I enter string value in a template and submit the form, it doesn't give any error messages at all and 'it is valid' is being printed.

```
def add_payment(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    payment_form = PaymentForm(request.POST)
    if payment_form.is_valid():
      print('it is valid')
  else:
    payment_form = PaymentForm()
  return render(request, 'testapp/add.html', {'payment_form': payment_form})
```

When i make the field required, the form gives the expected 'Enter a number' and the view - 'Required field' error message.

Any ideas how to make it work? Is this how django forms supposed to work? Because i couldn't find anything by googling.

Comment: does it prints **it is valid** ??

Comment: Exaclty what does `print(request.POST)` print?

Comment: "It is valid" is printed. 
print(request.POST) gives blank value for amount: 
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['V8vm7HuqdrKuAqr15wyztm62rLbncY5MAGp9wWY4646J1ZPspzFTNryFOLgfYKj0'], 'amount': ['']}>

Comment: Form is valid because amount got nothing. 

'amount': ['']

in Form amount is  required=False

Put some value when you submit the form then show print(request.POST)

Comment: The question wasn't actually django related, but had to do with HTML. That's why I wasn't able to find similar questions here on stackoverflow.

As I found out on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18852244/how-to-get-the-raw-value-an-input-type-number-field), "the browser is supposed to set the value to an empty string if the input isn't a valid floating point number."