# Large exponents returns empty in HTML input number

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I am trying to validate a number input and I noticed that invalid exponents(**1e**) and large exponents(**1e30000**) values returns empty strings.

The validation returns a message notifying the user that the field is empty, this is confusing as the users can see their input.

Please why is an empty string returned in these cases, and is there a way to get the actual values? Thanks!

Comment: Please share yourr code and problem properly. It's not clear

Comment: no way, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18852244/how-to-get-the-raw-value-an-input-type-number-field.