# Why this function for input with number only doesnt work actually with input type:number?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, input, numbers

```
$('input').on('keyup',function(){
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,'');
});
```

*From : https://stackoverflow.com/a/891816/622813*

After I tested with `<input type="number">`

When I type something like `1234a` so value is **blank**

But not with `<input type="text">` when I type `1234a` value is still `1234`

**Just wonder why ?**

**Demo :** http://jsfiddle.net/PV2fQ/

---

**Update :**

`<input type="tel">` this work good ... http://jsfiddle.net/PV2fQ/10/ **Why?**

Comment: Out of curiosity , I tried the above code on all browsers , the code works fine on Mozilla Firefox , Internet Explorer 11 and Apple safari (i.e. it just removes non numeric characters) but not on Google chrome & Opera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do a `console.log(this.value);` before your replace statement, you will see that for non-number inputs `<input type="number">` gets a blank value itself i.e `this.value = ''`;

This seems to be the internal implementation of this input type.

An alternative: http://jsfiddle.net/PV2fQ/12/

```
$('input').keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: what exactly would you like to happen and what type of input do you want to use?

Comment: Just want to use `type:number` becouse mobile keyboard will show number only... something like that

Comment: I believe that if type=number, the user will be shown only the number keyboard on the phone so you need not worry about them entering non-numbers on the field. Check [here](http://html5doctor.com/html5-forms-input-types/#input-number)

Comment: Yes but what about desktop browsers :P

Comment: nice.... maybe I will use that, But still wonder why its doesnt work good on type:number :D

Comment: @l2aelba: it does work well on number-type inputs. Too well even, in Firefox 30: type in a number plus a letter, and the whole input is deleted. For more information on the behavior of some new browsers with number-type inputs, although from a significantly different perspective, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24407109/new-webkits-convert-decimal-comma-to-dot-and-vice-versa-in-number-type-inputs. Just to show that there is something going on in browser world in this respect, that is not well defined by W3 standards. So, I would go with Nikhil's solution, if that works for you.