# Remove zero inside input when try to erase

Tags: javascript, html, input, reactjs

I have a react-component which is an input-field of the type number. When I press random numbers inside everything works fine, but when I want to erase everything there is always a zero inside the input-field which I can´t erase. Is is possible to blank out the input-field so that the zero disappear when I erase everything?

My component:

```
const NumberBox = (props) => {
  const onChanged = (event) => {
    props.onChange(+event.target.value);
  };

  const styles = {
    inputGeneral: {
    border: '0px',
    width: '100%',
    padding: '8px 16px',
    fontSize: '1.6em' } };

  return (
   <input
    style={styles.inputGeneral}
    type="number" 
    pattern="[0-9]*"
    value={props.value}
    onChange={onChanged}
  />);
 };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because of the behavior associated with the HTML5 number input type in Chromium (and possibly other browsers, too) ...

The simplest solution should be use `text` input type and manually validate/format your input...

See also this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5345095/chrome-auto-formats-input-number)...

Comment: This works fine the first time the input-field is shown, but if I type in any number and try to erase it the value in the input-field is set back to 0. One would think that the value would just be an empty string or something, but no ..

Comment: Why would you expect a blank string, it's a number input.

Comment: @HenrikAndersson If i erase everything in an input-field I wouldn´t expect the number 0. I would expect the input-field to be empty. Maybe not an empty string, but empty none the less.

Comment: Remember it is a **number** type field: which number is 'empty field' ? I would say '0'... That's why you see a '0' in an empty number input field... It is probably a matter of conventions, but I find it quite reasonable... :-)

Comment: @MarcoS i don't think it's reasonable by any means, 0 is a value, whereas empty is no value, which should be a separate and valid state. Imagine you're entering a score for a soccer game, 0 would be an actual score, but you should be able to clear that score by removing the value.